# OpenCV on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, opencv, windows-phone

How I can use OpenCV on Windows Phone 8.1 Universal in C#? I saw EmguCV but he has only commercial license for Windows Phone. Is possible other way to use OpenCV in C# on Windows Phone 8.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio's Windows store apps creation libraries allow you to design a UI out of pure XAML, for Windows phone 8.1RT and above, OpenCV binaries are availale, that let you mix code from XAML and OpenCV's...

Check this Repository: https://github.com/Microsoft/opencv

Hope it helps :)